# How to I apply a custom style for a third-party component in a single React component without affecting its style in other components?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am using a dropdown from `react-bootstrap` and its context-menu has a className called `Select-menu-outer`. I wanted to change the font size of this menu only in one component.

What I did was, I just created a new `css` file called `panel.css` and did `import './panel.css;` in my component.

In the `panel.css`, I applied the style to the `Select-menu-outer` like

```
.Select-menu-outer { font-size: 12px }
```

This worked fine, but it affected the font size of all other dropdowns in the entire app.

I would have used `CSS Modules` and do something like `import style from './panel.css` and do `className={style.Select-menu-outer}` something like that, but since this is a third-party library component, I wasn't sure if I can do that.

Any good way to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Add a new class list to the drop down you what to change called **.Select-menu-outer-size**
Then do this in your css:

```
.Select-menu-outer-size { font-size: 12px !important}
```

The !important overrides the other class.

### Javascript could be used!

let's say that it is the 3rd dropdown on that page with this class: `.Select-menu-outer`
So we do:

```
var addclass = document.getElementsByClassName("Select-menu-outer").[2];
addclass.classList.add("Select-menu-outer-size");
```

Then add you css:

```
.Select-menu-outer-size { font-size: 12px !important}
```

**Note:** 0 is 1 and 1 is 2 etc. for `document.getElementsByClassName("Select-menu-outer").[2];`
Linkhttps://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.aspfilename=tryjsref_document_getelementsbyclassname

Comment: But this is a third-party library and I cant really add a new class to it.

Comment: like this `class="Select-menu-outer Select-menu-outer-size"`

Comment: I mean I wont have direct access to this component that has that className

Comment: This seems like a silly thing to do if you're already using React.

Answer (score 0):

**If using React Bootstrap...**

You can use the `bsPrefix` prop to customize the class of your component, in order to style it via CSS.

> Change the underlying component CSS base class name and modifier class names prefix. This is an escape hatch for working with heavily customized bootstrap css.

Source: [React-Bootstrap docs](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/dropdowns/#customization)

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline-styles on that specific menu to override the default style.

OR

you can assign an id e.g. id="outer-menu" to that specific menu tag and access that menu with #outer-menu in CSS.

The priority of id is greater than className so it will probably override it.